# mongo near set maxDistance as value in collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, geolocation

I am sorry by the title. I was hard to describe. I have this collection

```
  {
      "_id" : ObjectId("55cb9c666c522cafdb053a68"),
      location: {
     type: "Point",
     coordinates: [-73.856077, 40.848447]
  },
      "maxDistancevalue" : 100000
  }
```

Now I want to find of the current location is within: 100000 as defined is the collection by "maxDistancevalue"

The code will be like this. But how set the maxDistancevalue?

```
  db.places.find(
     {
       location:
         { $near :
            {
              $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [ -73.9667, 40.78 ] },
              $minDistance: **??????, -->maxDistancevalue** 
              $maxDistance: 0
            }
         }
     }
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Aggregation Framework's [$geoNear](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) pipeline stage to reference other existing field. It requires 2dsphere index to be created on your collection, so start with:

```
db.places.createIndex({location:"2dsphere"});
```

and then you can run your `aggregate()` query:

```
db.places.aggregate([
    {
        $geoNear: {
            near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.9667, 40.78 ] },
            distanceField: "dist.calculated",
            maxDistance: "$maxDistancevalue"
        }
    }
])
```